# Server Side encryption in Dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

I was reading about the encryption at rest and found that Dynamodb by default does that. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.usagenotes.html

What does it actually mean? Because I can still see the data in AWS console in plain text. So, how it is in encrypted form?

Does it mean that in the actual storage form in machine it is encrypted? And the private/public keys are managed by the Dynamodb service itself?

Also, if I enable dynamodb stream for such table and connect the streams to a AWS Lambda, then I can see the data in plain text in lambda. Then, how come it is encrypted?

Can someone please explain what I am missing? Is there any way to validate that Dynamodb is really encrypting our data?

Comment: DynamoDB supports encryption at rest. That means that it is encrypted on the DynamoDB servers, but not when it is transmitted to any client (such as the AWS console or a lambda function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted on the page you cited:

> Encryption at rest only encrypts data while it is static (at rest) on a persistent storage media.

That is the purpose of encryption at rest -- protecting the data against compromise of the disks where it is stored.  Such compromise is highly unlikely in AWS, which has [many layers of security](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/data-center/controls/) including time-limited, least-privilege physical access and media decommissioning policies... but that is the purpose of encryption at rest, which is required in some cases (such as some regulated industries).

It is transparent to you as a user of the service.  You see the data in the clear in the console and in streams because it's decrypted when read from the disks where DynamoDB stores it, just as it is encrypted as it is written.

There is not a way to prove that this encryptio  is occurring with DynamoDB, other than relying on AWS's assertion that it is indeed occurring as documented -- it's a feaure that can't be disabled.

The data is also encrypted in transit -- API interactions, handoffs to other services (e.g. Lambda), and the AWS console itself all use TLS (SSL) which also provides matching, transparent decryption on the other end.  The exception here would be if you are using an SDK or a third party client library and you disable HTTPS (or the third party library doesn't implement it).